# android:Wants to consult about Dialog adding button Dilemma

Tags: android

I have this code for making dialog:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.setTitle("AA");
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setText("BB");
d.setContentView(tv);
d.show();
```

I am looking for any way to add 2 buttons to this dialog and catch the button press event?

Thanks

Comment: like this? http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/07/android-alertdialog-example.html

Answer (score 2):

I would use `AlertDialog.Builder` instead of `Dialog` constructor:

```
AlertDilog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
ad.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
ad.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.dialog_message);
ad.setCancelable(true);

ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1, this.getString(R.string.first_btn_label), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Do something when the first button is pressed
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_SOLVED);
    }
}); 

ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON2, this.getString(R.string.second_btn_label), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Do something when the second button is pressed
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_SOLVED);
    }
}); 

//You can even add a third button if you want to
/*
ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON3, this.getString(R.string.third_btn_label), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Do something when the third button is pressed
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_SOLVED);
    }
}); 
*/

ad.show();
```